# How to fix "SyntaxError: name 'filename' is used prior to global declaration"

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, tkinter, scope

I am using python tkinter to make a text editor. I am trying to work out the logic of how to save the file the first time with a dialog box (so you can set the file name), and all the other times without. Here is the code I have so far:

```
filename = ""
def save():

input_data = textinput.get("1.0", "1000000.0")

try:
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(input_data)
        f.close()

except IOError:
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir="/documents", title="Save file", defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("HTML files", ".html"), ("All file types", ".*")])
    global filename
    filename = file.name
    file.write(input_data)
    file.close()
```

`input_data` is the text field contents, and the `save()` function is called when they push the save button.

I am trying to make it so the first time when you click save, the `filename` variable has not been assigned to the file path and name, so it does the IOError, that opens the box and saves the file. It also sets a global `filename` as seen here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function). But this error is given: `SyntaxError: name 'filename' is used prior to global declaration`. It is, but that is what the link said to do. How can I solve this problem?  Thanks for any help in advance! xD

Comment: Why not have `global filename = '' ` as the first line of the code? And then you won't need to use `global ` keyword in the `except` clause.

Comment: Now it is showing this: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 2):

A `global` statement needs to be placed above the first use of a variable, even if that first use is just reading the existing value, not assigning to it.

In your code, you're trying to use `filename` in your `open` call, within the `with` statement. The `global` statement occurs later, when you're trying to assign to the global `filename` variable.

The easy fix is to just move the `global` statement up to the top of the function:

```
filename = ""
def save():
    global filename                                # move the global statement up here
    input_data = textinput.get("1.0", "1000000.0")

    try:
        with open(filename, "w") as f:             # so it's above this use of filename
            f.write(input_data)
            f.close()
    
    except IOError:
        file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir="/documents", title="Save file", defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("HTML files", ".html"), ("All file types", ".*")])
        filename = file.name                      # not only the assignment down here
        file.write(input_data)
        file.close()
```

A better approach is probably to not use a global variable at all, and instead use an instance of a class to hold the filename, but that's a more disruptive change.

Comment: I am slightly confused. Can you add your solution to my code as an example?

Comment: I've edited to put the change in context, within the function. Hopefully it will make more sense now, especially with the comments in the code.

Comment: Is there something I am missing? It is giving this error: "NameError: name 'filename' is not defined" But it is!

Comment: Have you omitted the very first line of the code in your question, where you initialize `filename` outside of the function, with `filename = ""`?

Comment: Yes, I am really sorry, but it is still not working

Comment: `filename = ""` should not be removed.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. You *do* need to *keep* that line, you'll get the error if you remove it. I omitted it from my rewrite of the code because it doesn't need to change (originally I was not including the full function in my answer, so adding a copy of the setup initialization code never crossed my mind).